# IIS Server: URL rewriting requests from PHP site for its App pool

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting, application-pool, iis-10

I have a PHP site hosted on localhost IIS Server 10. Site has applications from app pool. This is request sample from IIS logs:

```
2017-04-14 09:33:51 ::1 POST /api/Registration/BeginRegistration - 80 - ::1 GuzzleHttp/6.0.2+curl/7.51.0+PHP/5.6.30 - 404 0 0 59
```

There are some tricky addressing rules there, so I need to redirect requests from site like `/api/Registration/BeginRegistration` to `/myapi/api/Registration/BeginRegistration`.

My application's addresses are like `http://localhost/myapi/api/Registration/BeginRegistration`.

I've tried IIS url rewriting, but something does not work. How to do it properly? Thanks.